# R: Update observation ID by comparing its value against a range of values given by two other columns

Tags: r

I am comparing road data between two years. The information gives a unique code for each road (id.agg), a unique code for each segment of the road (id), the intital and final kilometers for each segment (ini, fin) and the year.

When I merge the two tables using their unique segment id, I realized that there are mismatches due to road construction. However based on the kilometer covered by  the segments, the roads' extent are the same. Therefore I would like to find a way to correct older ids with update ids.

A subset of my combined data looks like this:

```
 >trial
   id.agg         id year.x ini.x fin.x year.y ini.y fin.y
   010BTO 010BTO0318      1 606.1 611.7      2 606.1 611.7
   010BTO 010BTO0320      1 611.7 631.4      2 611.7 631.4
   010BTO 010BTO0325      1 631.4 670.2      2 631.4 670.2
   010BTO 010BTO0330      1 670.2 718.4      2 670.2 718.4
   010BTO 010BTO0335      1 718.4 734.0      2 718.4 786.8
   010BTO 010BTO0340      1 734.0 772.9     NA    NA    NA
   010BTO 010BTO0345      1 772.9 786.8     NA    NA    NA
   010BTO 010BTO0350      1 786.8 794.9      2 786.8 794.9
   010BTO 010BTO0355      1 794.9 828.2      2 794.9 827.2
   010BTO 010BTO0357     NA    NA    NA      2 827.2 828.2
   020BPI 020BPI0370      1   0.0  40.3      2   0.0  54.3
   020BPI 020BPI0375      1  40.3  54.3     NA    NA    NA
   020BPI 020BPI0380      1  54.3  85.3      2  54.3  85.3
   020BPI 020BPI0390      1  85.3 148.3      2  85.3 148.3
  >
```

For thos NAs in year 2, I would like to update the id so that I can compare which segments of road in year 1 are reflected in year 2. I thought to compare the initial kilometers in year 1 (ini.x) with the range of kilometers in year 2. I tried the following:

```
> trial[is.na(trial$year.y) & trial$ini.x %between% list(trial$ini.y,trial$fin.y) %in% trial$ini.y,]
   id.agg         id year.x ini.x fin.x year.y ini.y fin.y
6  010BTO 010BTO0340      1 734.0 772.9     NA    NA    NA
7  010BTO 010BTO0345      1 772.9 786.8     NA    NA    NA
12 020BPI 020BPI0375      1  40.3  54.3     NA    NA    NA
>
```

This shows me those observations for which I would like to correct their ids but I still do not find solutions to two major issues to solve my problem:

1) How do I know to which specific id is the query finding a match?
  2) How can this be applied comparing per group (i.e. id.agg) and not through the whole vector?

Question 1) is important to be able to assign the update id to the old id. Question 2) is important as my real dataframe has over 6000 observations and around 500 groups, so I am pretty sure without accounting for groups I would find false matches (e.g. the ini.x would be found in the range [ini.y,fin.y] for more than one group)

I would like to have a dataframe like this:

```
>trial
id.agg         id year.x ini.x fin.x year.y ini.y fin.y corrected.id
010BTO 010BTO0318      1 606.1 611.7      2 606.1 611.7   010BTO0318
010BTO 010BTO0320      1 611.7 631.4      2 611.7 631.4   010BTO0320
010BTO 010BTO0325      1 631.4 670.2      2 631.4 670.2   010BTO0325
010BTO 010BTO0330      1 670.2 718.4      2 670.2 718.4   010BTO0330
010BTO 010BTO0335      1 718.4 734.0      2 718.4 786.8   010BTO0335
010BTO 010BTO0340      1 734.0 772.9     NA    NA    NA   010BTO0335
010BTO 010BTO0345      1 772.9 786.8     NA    NA    NA   010BTO0335
010BTO 010BTO0350      1 786.8 794.9      2 786.8 794.9   010BTO0350
010BTO 010BTO0355      1 794.9 828.2      2 794.9 827.2   010BTO0355
010BTO 010BTO0357     NA    NA    NA      2 827.2 828.2   010BTO0357
020BPI 020BPI0370      1   0.0  40.3      2   0.0  54.3   020BPI0370
020BPI 020BPI0375      1  40.3  54.3     NA    NA    NA   020BPI0370
020BPI 020BPI0380      1  54.3  85.3      2  54.3  85.3   020BPI0380
020BPI 020BPI0390      1  85.3 148.3      2  85.3 148.3   020BPI0390
>
```

I have been looking to solutions but I cannot find a function or code that helps me to address point 1). In point 2) I found that group_by combined with %>% might help but I do not manage to apply it even to my query show aboved. For instance:

```
> trial %>% 
+   group_by(id.agg) %>% 
+   which( is.na(trial$year.y) & trial$ini.x %between% list(trial$ini.y,trial$fin.y) %in% trial$ini.y, 
+          arr.ind=TRUE)
Error in which(., is.na(trial$year.y) & trial$ini.x %between% list(trial$ini.y,  : 
argument to 'which' is not logical
>
```

Any thoughts or leads on how to solve this would be truly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

## -----------

As follow up, I used the proposed solution. It does well in identifying which observations fall in the previous non_NA observation's range of (ini.y,fin.y). Here is a subset of the output I got:

```
  id.agg         id year.x ini.x fin.x year.y ini.y fin.y rownum corrected.id
1 424BAL 424BAL0175   2016  39.5  42.7   2017  39.5  42.7      8   424BAL0175
2 424BAL 424BAL0180   2016  42.7  44.3   2017  42.7  50.8      9   424BAL0180
3 424BAL 424BAL0185   2016  44.3  47.1     NA    NA    NA      9   424BAL0180
4 424BAL 424BAL0190   2016  47.1  52.3     NA    NA    NA      9   424BAL0180
5 424BAL 424BAL0195   2016  52.3  55.0     NA    NA    NA     12   424BAL0195
6 424BAL 424BAL0200   2016  55.0  64.4     NA    NA    NA     13   424BAL0200
7 424BAL 424BAL0205   2016  64.4  68.1     NA    NA    NA     14   424BAL0205
8 424BAL 424BAL0210   2016  68.1  70.4   2017  50.8  73.8     15   424BAL0210
9 424BAL 424BAL0230   2016  70.4  77.2   2017  73.8  80.6     16   424BAL0230
```

Notice that observations in rows 4-6 are not in the range of (ini.y,fin.y) of observation in row 2 but on that of observation in row 8. The expected output should look like this:

```
  id.agg         id year.x ini.x fin.x year.y ini.y fin.y rownum corrected.id
1 424BAL 424BAL0175   2016  39.5  42.7   2017  39.5  42.7      8   424BAL0175
2 424BAL 424BAL0180   2016  42.7  44.3   2017  42.7  50.8      9   424BAL0180
3 424BAL 424BAL0185   2016  44.3  47.1     NA    NA    NA      9   424BAL0180
4 424BAL 424BAL0190   2016  47.1  52.3     NA    NA    NA      9   424BAL0180
5 424BAL 424BAL0195   2016  52.3  55.0     NA    NA    NA     12   424BAL0210
6 424BAL 424BAL0200   2016  55.0  64.4     NA    NA    NA     13   424BAL0210
7 424BAL 424BAL0205   2016  64.4  68.1     NA    NA    NA     14   424BAL0210
8 424BAL 424BAL0210   2016  68.1  70.4   2017  50.8  73.8     15   424BAL0210
9 424BAL 424BAL0230   2016  70.4  77.2   2017  73.8  80.6     16   424BAL0230
```

Sincerily greatful in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly then this should help

```r
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(id.agg) %>%
  mutate(rownum=ifelse(is.na(year.y) & is.na(ini.y) & is.na(fin.y), NA, row_number())) %>%
  mutate(rownum=ifelse(is.na(rownum) & ini.x >=na.locf(ini.y) & ini.x <= na.locf(fin.y), 
                       na.locf(rownum), 
                       na.locf(rownum, fromLast=T))) %>%
  mutate(corrected.id = id[rownum]) %>%
  select(-rownum)
```

**Output is:**

```
  id.agg id         year.x ini.x fin.x year.y ini.y fin.y corrected.id
  <chr>  <chr>       <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
1 424BAL 424BAL0175   2016  39.5  42.7   2017  39.5  42.7 424BAL0175  
2 424BAL 424BAL0180   2016  42.7  44.3   2017  42.7  50.8 424BAL0180  
3 424BAL 424BAL0185   2016  44.3  47.1     NA  NA    NA   424BAL0180  
4 424BAL 424BAL0190   2016  47.1  52.3     NA  NA    NA   424BAL0180  
5 424BAL 424BAL0195   2016  52.3  55.0     NA  NA    NA   424BAL0210  
6 424BAL 424BAL0200   2016  55.0  64.4     NA  NA    NA   424BAL0210  
7 424BAL 424BAL0205   2016  64.4  68.1     NA  NA    NA   424BAL0210  
8 424BAL 424BAL0210   2016  68.1  70.4   2017  50.8  73.8 424BAL0210  
9 424BAL 424BAL0230   2016  70.4  77.2   2017  73.8  80.6 424BAL0230
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <-structure(list(id.agg = c("424BAL", "424BAL", "424BAL", "424BAL", 
"424BAL", "424BAL", "424BAL", "424BAL", "424BAL"), id = c("424BAL0175", 
"424BAL0180", "424BAL0185", "424BAL0190", "424BAL0195", "424BAL0200", 
"424BAL0205", "424BAL0210", "424BAL0230"), year.x = c(2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), ini.x = c(39.5, 
42.7, 44.3, 47.1, 52.3, 55, 64.4, 68.1, 70.4), fin.x = c(42.7, 
44.3, 47.1, 52.3, 55, 64.4, 68.1, 70.4, 77.2), year.y = c(2017L, 
2017L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2017L, 2017L), ini.y = c(39.5, 42.7, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.8, 73.8), fin.y = c(42.7, 50.8, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 73.8, 80.6)), .Names = c("id.agg", "id", "year.x", 
"ini.x", "fin.x", "year.y", "ini.y", "fin.y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

**Edit:** Updated code after getting a better clarity of the requirement.

Comment: Many thanks @Prem! I tried the solution you proposed on my whole dataframe (7000 observations) and did not fully solved my problem. As I understand your solution, it will correct my id's with the last non-NA value within a group. However, in my case it is important to also account for that the initial km in year 1 are within the range of kilometers in year 2. I tried to combine your solution with a condition like the one I posted above and I cannot get a way around it.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood it but let's check out the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for not replying before. I was trying to work with the edited answer. Based on the example (above) in which the output was not correct. Now the code does well to assign the corrected id for those that are within the range (ini.y,fin.y) but for those that are not, it does not correct the id value and maintain the original id. I am trying to use the code but including %>% fill(rownum, .direction="up") and does not make the trick.

Comment: What values do you want to impute in case it doesn't fall within ranges? You should edit your post to show us the desired output in this case.

Comment: I made the editions. I apologize if I have not been fully clear since the beginning. Thanks for engaging!

Comment: Many thanks @Prem. This seems to work fine on this example. I was just hoping to find a more flexible way in which I do not depend on the previous or next non-NA values to assign the corrected id. Instead to directly find the rownum that matches ini.y<=x.ini<=fin.y for each row in the dataframe. I was thinking by using %in% year.y fbut it did not work. In any case, it has been great help!

Comment: Just one thing. On your answer, the line of select(-rownum) did not work, but if I take it out it does.

Comment: `select(-rownum)` is used to drop temporary variable `rownum` as we don't require it in the final output. If 'minus' sign is used before variable name in `select` then it drops that variable else it select that variable only.